# Child process not getting created when called from winform button event function?

Tags: c#, python, winforms

I am trying to run a python code from my UI. i am using the code below to do so,

```
Process p = new Process();
            string cmd = @"python filepath & exit";
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            p.Start();
            StreamWriter myStreamWriter = p.StandardInput;
            myStreamWriter.WriteLine(cmd.ToString());
            myStreamWriter.Close();
            string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            p.WaitForExit();
            Console.WriteLine(output);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

the above code opens a cmd prompt and executes the python file.
this code runs fine when i test it using a console application but it doesn't work when i use it within the event function for "run" button in my UI application. Is there any particular reason for it?

Comment: What happens if you set StartInfo.UseShellExecute to true? I know you'll get a cmd window appear, but python might need the shell to run properly.

Comment: @DavidArno if i set startinfo.useshellexecute to true then i won't be able to redirect my input and output.

Comment: good point. I clearly didn't think that one through. Sorry. :)

Comment: OK, so when you say "t doesn't work when i use it within the event function", in what way doesn't it work? Does the method get called? Do you get an exception? Does output get set to anything?

Comment: @DavidArno i don't get any exception.....i just get a blank console window, there is no output shown for the program i run.

Comment: Rather than using stdin to send your python command to the cmd window, what happens if you set the sStartInfo arguments to "/c python ..." so that cmd invokes python directly?